# Train YOLOV8 with new class

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I have a completely new class x. I want to use YOLOV8 pretrained model, but this model was trained on coco with 80 classes which specified in a yaml file. Can I only replace the label name after the label number 0 with my new class x and delete the other 79 classes specification in the yaml without modifying other parameters or model structure?

I tried and it has no detection even if I see the loss converges to about 0.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to train the model on labeled examples of this new class, just changing the *coco.yaml* file will not help. Compose a new dataset with all classes you need to predict, create a new *.yaml* file for this dataset, including a path to it and a new names list, where class indexes must match the labels.

Load the model from *.pt* file, and train it on this new dataset. Pretrained weights still will help you to train a model on new classes faster than if you started from scratch.